# How to know the ranking of the scientific journal (class A, B or C)?

Tags: publications, journals

I want a website that gives me the recent ranking (according to classes A, B or C) for journals.

Thanks

Comment: Which field and according to what criteria?

Comment: @Aolon, in computer science.

Comment: The question seems to be based on the rather odd assumption that there exists a one and only authoritative ranking of journals.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the journal name on [scimagojr](https://www.scimagojr.com/). Moreover, you can use [CORE](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/) for conferences.

Comment: @Lee, I can not comment on your second question, but different metrics have different ranking systems. I am also in the Computer Science field. We mainly refer to CORE ranking for conferences (e.g., A*, A, B, etc.) and best quartile for journals (e.g., Q1, Q2, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A literature database service like Web of Science (commercial product by Clarivate, consult your research librarian) assigns topics to the journals indexed by them.  You then may see how well this one does *in comparison* to the others in the same field (added blue box):

[image]

([figure credit](https://www.massey.ac.nz/massey/research/library/library-services/research-services/publish/ranking-impact-jcr.cfm))

On occasion, you not only get a figure of merit, but a graph to follow-up the development, e.g., in Elsevier's scopus:

[image]

([figure credit](https://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=282982&p=3408328))

Comment: Just a small addition: if you already are in Web of Science, you also can get a graph of the journal scores over time (in the Journal Citation Reports you see mentioned in the first image you show). At least that is how I did it today...